# How to use hashcat on CentOS 7 to crack WPA with wordlist?

Tags: wpa

If we have a CentOS 7 desktop and a big wordlist and a WPA out.ivs capture (--ivs with airodump-ng), how can we use hashcat (without installing it via the package manager) to use the wordlist to "attack" the .ivs capture file to guess the password?

Comment: Indeed. If you don't want to install hashcat, try live-booting Kali Linux. It has all the tools preinstalled.

Comment: well, I posted it as answer. I just don't get it why isn't it needed to give hashcat the SSID? I know it's in the ivs file, but aircrack-ng needs it, why doesn't hashcat needs it?

Comment: @LoukiosValentine79 Likely because hashcat can (and does) crack multiple hashes at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the ivs file to hccap:

```
aircrack-ng out.ivs -J out.hccap
```

and then:

```
hashcat --words-skip=0 --hash-type=2500 --outfile=cracked.txt --threads=4 out.hccap WORDLIST.txt
```

I tried the latest aircrack-ng and hashcat on a T450 with an Ubuntu 15 LiveCD. aircrack-ng did ~1700 pw/sec, hashcat did ~1600-1650 pw/sec. Both were using 4 cores, "htop" showd it.

Comment: Couple of updates: 1) Modern hashcat can use GPU (via OpenCL), so performance is quite a bit better - 400,000 hashes/sec on a GTX 1080; and 2) current Kali support for OpenCL is spotty; a non-Kali distro is currently (2018) recommended.

Comment: In newer hashcat versions hccapx format is used instead of hccap, so use lower-case `-j` flag instead (read `man aircrack-ng`)